# Jumping from a source block to the tangled file

Tags: org-babel

Is there an inverse of `org-babel-tangle-jump-to-org` allowing one to jump from a source block to the corresponding place in the tangled file?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution if you use `:comments link` in your code blocks header and if tangle multiple blocks into a single file. With cursor at code block it will jump to a point where this block was tangled using these comment links.

```lisp
;; this is optional but might look better than defaults
(setq org-babel-tangle-comment-format-beg "-------->>  [[%link][%source-name]]")
(setq org-babel-tangle-comment-format-end "--------<<  %source-name ends here\n\n")

(defun sv-org-babel-tangle-jump-to-src ()
  "The opposite of `org-babel-tangle-jump-to-org'. Jumps at tangled code from org src block."
  (interactive)
  (if (org-in-src-block-p)
      (let* ((header (car (org-babel-tangle-single-block 1 'only-this-block)))
             (tangle (car header))
             (lang (caadr header))
             (buffer (nth 2 (cadr header)))
             (org-id (nth 3 (cadr header)))
             (source-name (nth 4 (cadr header)))
             (search-comment (org-fill-template
                              org-babel-tangle-comment-format-beg
                              `(("link" . ,org-id) ("source-name" . ,source-name))))
             (file (expand-file-name
                    (org-babel-effective-tangled-filename buffer lang tangle))))
        (if (not (file-exists-p file))
            (message "File does not exist. 'org-babel-tangle' first to create file.")
          (find-file file)
          (beginning-of-buffer)
          (search-forward search-comment)))
    (message "Cannot jump to tangled file because point is not at org src block.")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a function shipped with org that jumps to the tangled file.
Furthermore, there is no separate function that generates the file name(s) for the tangled file(s) in `org-babel-tangle`. That makes the job a bit cumbersome.

The function `org-babel-tangle-jump` calls `org-babel-tangle` with `write-region` temporarily modified such that it does **not** write the region contents to a file but just delivers the file name that is passed to it in a  variable `file` locally bound in `org-babel-tangle-jump`. Finally, `org-babel-tangle-jump` opens the file with that name if it already exists.

```el
(defun org-babel-tangle-jump ()
  "Jump to tangle file for the source block at point."
  (interactive)
  (let (file org-babel-pre-tangle-hook org-babel-post-tangle-hook)
    (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'write-region) (lambda (start end filename &rest _ignore)
                         (setq file filename)))
          ((symbol-function 'delete-file) #'ignore))
      (org-babel-tangle '(4)))
    (when file
      (setq file (expand-file-name file))
      (if (file-readable-p file)
      (find-file file)
    (error "Cannot open tangle file %S" file)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

A little add up to Stas' fantastic function:

as org-babel-tangle-single-block is used with counter 1, the function only work if your source block is the **first in the subtree**, or if it **have** `#+name: some name` **before the block**.

explanation:

if the src block have no `#+name:`, the link in tangle file would be

- `[[file:babel.org::+begin_src python][No heading:2]]` (if it is before first heading) or
- `[[file:babel.org::*a heading][a heading:1]]` ("a heading" is the heading it belongs to)

and the counter in `[No heading:2]`  and `[a heading:1]`may not be 1.

With `#+name:` the link would look like
`[[file:babel.org::this block][this block]]`, where the counter wouldn't matter.